# Unicoin bug, not accepting payment

Tags: bug, unicoins

Unicoins have opened up a world of possibilities for SE users, instant answers, purchasable reputation, all of these changes have been long awaited and I'm happy to see that SE is listening to its users. Unfortunately, surely due to the huge demand, the payment portals are down and therefore I cannot pour my hard earned money into appearing more intelligent than I am. Please reopen the payment portals or accept my first born child in exchange for reputation!

Comment: `accept my first born child in exchange for reputation` - I accept. UPS ur kid

Comment: Why give your first born child for this??? *Get that kid working on mining!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to excessive traffic, the payment methods will not be back up and running until tomorrow!

Although, you CAN cheat the system a little bit.

Here are some steps:

1. Employ a unicorn
2. Feed said unicorn
3. Feed the unicorn some more
4. Try to pet the unicorn
5. Apologize for crossing the bounderies of personal space
6. Beg for forgiveness
7. Ask for unicoins
8. Get angry about unicorn not giving you unicoins
9. Mug the unicorn, take his wallet, grab his unicoins.
10. Run

Repeat if necessary.

Comment: step 11 is surely death by impalement, standard punishment in the unicorn court of law for scamming a unicorn.

Comment: That's why step 10 is 'run'.

Comment: you've clearly never seen a unicorn chase a thief. That only delays step 11 by a few seconds.

Comment: Instructions unclear, got stuck in washing machine

Answer (score 8):

As BeatAlex notes, high volume has caused problems for some of the systems involved with converting to and from Unicoins.

I want to reassure you that our payment processor - Pinochle Online eXchange - is still solvent and working hard to resolve these issues. There is ZERO truth to the rumors that their CEO spent their entire reserve of Unicoins on waffles.

Comment: What about unimplemented options? when will you be able to roll-out bacon payment services?